# How to convert string into int array

Tags: java

Hello how to convert String into int array.  I need it for some enrypting.
Just a String converted into 32 bit values.

I tried that but it did not work. Maybe converting String into BigInteger then this into raw String then into int array would work?

```
String s = "Alice";
int[] tab = s.getBytes();
```

Comment: How would you convert "Alice" to an int array with pen and paper?  What would you expect the result to be?

Comment: getBytes() returns byte[] and not int[]

Comment: im guessing he wants it as a byte array but he assumes bytes are held as number and assumes numbers are always ints? My guess anyway lol.

Comment: I had hope that bye and int are in covariance.

Comment: [Covariance?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)

Comment: The rules of primitive widening conversion does not apply to primitive arrays covariance. That is, a byte is automatically promoted to int as part of widening primitive conversion when you assign a byte to an integer, right?; however this does not mean that a byte[] can be assigned to int[]. Both, byte[] and int[] are direct descendants of Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this would work for ya:  Found it here: http://pro-programmers.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-byte-array-into-int-array.html

```
public int[] toIntArray(byte[] barr) { 
        //Pad the size to multiple of 4 
        int size = (barr.length / 4) + ((barr.length % 4 == 0) ? 0 : 1);       

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(size *4); 
        bb.put(barr); 

        //Java uses Big Endian. Network program uses Little Endian. 
        bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN); 
        bb.rewind(); 
        IntBuffer ib =  bb.asIntBuffer();         
        int [] result = new int [size]; 
        ib.get(result); 


        return result; 
}
```

To call it:

```
String s = "Alice";     
int[] tab = toIntArray(s.getBytes());
```

Comment: Thank man! It works but i changed it into ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN
The thing I really need is 
        Message precalculated array on 32 bit values; 
         the length is a multiple of 16, the bit after
         the last message bit is set, the last 64 bits
         represent the message length in big endian order
And i get confused about it. I've made yesterday RSA,DSA, but I don't know how to do it. It is from a book which desribes SHA-1 coding.

Comment: @RobertKilar - np... glad I could help out.  I corrected the ByteOrder in the post for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are converting a String to an int array please read [Joel's article on String encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), it is not as obvious as you may think.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
String s = "1234";
int[] intArray = new int[s.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
}
```

Comment: Before answering, check the OP's example. His string contains no number whatsoever.

Comment: I just need convert String into 32 bit value array.

Answer (score 0):

change to byte : `byte[] tab = s.getBytes();`

```
final String s = "54321";
final byte[] b = s.getBytes();
for (final byte element : b) {
    System.out.print(element+" ");
}
```

Output :

> 53 52 51 50 49

**Edit**

`(int)` cast is removed by Eclipse in `System.out.print((int) element+" ");`

Unless you want to cast `int myInteger = (int) tab[n]`,  you have to copy `byte[]` in a new  `int[]`

Comment: @m0skit0: I am sure the difference between int[] and byte[] doesn't matter for the OP.

Comment: @Vlad Eclipse do no compile with *int*

Comment: I just need convert String into 32 bit value array.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String s = "Alice";
        byte[] derp = s.getBytes();

        int[] tab = new int[derp.length];

        for (int i=0; i< derp.length; i++)
            tab[i] = (int)derp[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a string to bytes without an encoding.
You need to use this already existing method:

```
public static final byte[] getBytesUtf8( String string )
  {
      if ( string == null )
      {
          return new byte[0];
      }

      try
      {
          return string.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
      }
      catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException uee )
      {
          return new byte[]
              {};
      }
  }
}
```

Then change it to int array like this:  `byte[] bAlice`

```
int[] iAlice = new int[bAlice.length];

for (int index = 0; index < bAlice.length; ++index) {
     iAlice [index] = (int)bAlice[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules of [widening primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) does not apply to arrays of primitive types. For instance, it is valid to assign a byte to an integer in Java:

```
byte b = 10;
int i = b; //b is automatically promoted (widened) to int
```

However, primitive arrays do not behave the same way, and therefore, you cannot assume that an array of `byte[]` is going to be automatically promoted to an array of `int[]`.

However, you could force the promotion of every item in your byte array manually:

```
String text = "Alice";
byte[] source = text.getBytes();
int[] destiny = new int[source.length];
for(int i = 0; i < source.length; i++){
    destiny[i] = source[i]; //automatically promotes byte to int.
}
```

For me, this would be the simplest approach.